# How use dots and dashes in EL expression in alfresco and activity?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, el, activiti

Alfresco docs suggest to use name spaces and declare beans like that:

```
<bean id="module-artifact-id.myBeanName" class="com.sc.MyBeanClass"/>
```

ANd it is ok. But when I try to use sam definition in activity:

```
<activiti:eventListener delegateExpression= "${module-artifact-id.myBeanName}" />
```

I got:

```
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${module-artifact-id.myBeanName}
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:53)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.DelegateExpressionActivitiEventListener.onEvent(DelegateExpressionActivitiEventListener.java:46)
    at org.activiti.engine.delegate.event.impl.ActivitiEventSupport.dispatchEvent(ActivitiEventSupport.java:105)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier 'module'
```

It seems that EL expression do not support `-` and `.` (the latter is recognized as metho calls).

Any workarounds how to use dashed and dots in EL expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use replacing "-" with "\u002D" as shown below:

```
<activiti:eventListener delegateExpression= "${module\\u002Dartifact\\u002Did.myBeanName}" />
```